# table-per-hierarchy with references to same parent type: deletes are cascaded on different type of subclass

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a common superclass (suppose it's `Employee`), which has (amongst others) subclasses `Engineer` and `Salesman`.
The table structure of the `Employee` classes are modelled using table-per-hierarchy.

A `Department` object references both salesmen and engineers:

```
public class Department
    {
        public IEnumerable<Engineer> Engineers { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Salesman> Salesmen { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem occurs when I empty the `Engineer`s collection from the `Department`:

- When both relationships are mapped with `cascade=none` or `cascade=all` (on the `Department` side), then all the `Salesman` records get their foreign-key set to null (here is the statement generated by nHib: `UPDATE dbo.Employee SET Department_id = Null WHERE Department_id = @p0;`.
- When both relationships are mapped with `cascade=all-delete-orphan` then I get an `ObjectDeletedException` referring to a completly different collection of the `Department` object (can't figure this one out)
- when mapped with `cascade=all` or `cascade=none` and table *per subclass* strategy, all seems to be working fine
- when mapped with `cascade=all-delete-orphan` and table *per subclass* strategy, I once again get the `ObjectDeletedException` referring to a completly different collection of the `Department` object

obviously I'm missing some nHib basic here.. but what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

duhh.... `inverse=true` on the parent class for those collections.
still not sure what caused that seemingly-unrelated `ObjectDeletedException` though...